# Flutter Works in the Command Line But Not in CMDER

Tags: windows, flutter, cmd, command-line, cmder

I have just downloaded flutter onto my computer and double clicked on the `flutter_console` file.  It opened up the regular Windows Terminal.  I then entered in the command `flutter doctor` and everything worked as it is supposed to.

I then opened up `cmder` and typed in the same command:  `flutter doctor`.  And I got the following message:

```
'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Why is it working in the regular windows command terminal, but not cmder.  And what can I do so that it does work in cmder?

Thanks.

Comment: Let me suggest to delete this thread, because there are literally thousands of posts like that with `PATH` not properly set... Nevertheless, take a look at this: [What is the reason for “X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41454769)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out -- I had to set my PATH variables to recognize where the bin file in the flutter folder was located.